# Codeforces: 377-A Maze, Why is this code not working?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search, graph-traversal

I tried to solve a question in Codeforces: [Maze](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/377/A)

From editorial, I understood that I just need to perform a DFS to solve this question. Here are the exact words from [Editorial](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/10157):

> Start BFS or DFS from any free cell.  As the maze is connected, this
> search will visit all s free cells.  But we can stop the search when
> it visits s - k free cells.  It's obvious that these s - k cells are
> connected to each other.  Remaining k cells can be transformed into
> the walls.

My [solution](https://codeforces.com/contest/377/submission/87407476) for this is:

```
n, m, k = map(int, input().split())
arr = [list(input()) for _ in range(n)]  # The maze

if k == 0:  # if no wall needed, print maze as it is and exit
    for row in arr:
        for element in row:
            print(element, end="")
        print("")
    exit(0)

x, y = -1, -1  # indices to start DFS with, x and y can point to any cell which is '.' (empty)
to_visit = -k  # the number of connected components of graph we need to visit(remaining '.' cells will be marked as 'X')
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        if arr[i][j] == '.':
            to_visit += 1
            x = i
            y = j


s = [(x, y)]  # a stack for performing DFS
while to_visit > 0 and len(s) > 0:
    i, j = s.pop()
    arr[i][j] = '?'  # make it anything other than '.', '#' and 'X', to mark it visited.
    #                  so we can later remaining '.' to 'X' and change '?' to '.'
    to_visit -= 1
    # top
    if i > 0 and arr[i - 1][j] == '.':
        s.append((i - 1, j))
    # bottom
    if i < n - 1 and arr[i + 1][j] == '.':
        s.append((i + 1, j))
    # left
    if j > 0 and arr[i][j - 1] == '.':
        s.append((i, j - 1))
    # right
    if j < m - 1 and arr[i][j + 1] == '.':
        s.append((i, j + 1))


for row in arr:
    for element in row:
        if element == '?':
            print('.', end="")
        elif element == '.':
            print('X', end="")
        else:
            print(element, end="")
    print("")
```

This code is giving wrong answer in Test Case 10 of codeforces but, due to the nature of codeforces website, I do not have access to this Test Case.

I have tried to solve this question more than [20 times](https://codeforces.com/contest/377/my) still couldn't get it accepted.

I can see other's solutions in the website but why is my code not working?

**Note:** This is not a homework problem and is not a part of any currently running competition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add an element in a stack i.e s, you should mark that cell with a different symbol so that you can't add that cell again in the stack. Otherwise, it leads to the counting of the same cell as empty space more than a single time. By making these changes in your code, all the test cases were passed.

Check the code below(**ACCEPTED**):

```
n, m, k = map(int, input().split())
arr = [list(input()) for _ in range(n)]  # The maze

if k == 0:  # if no wall needed, print maze as it is and exit
    for row in arr:
        for element in row:
            print(element, end="")
        print("")
    exit(0)

x, y = -1, -1  # indices to start DFS with, x and y can point to any cell which is '.' (empty)
to_visit = -k  # the number of connected components of graph we need to visit(remaining '.' cells will be marked as 'X')
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        if arr[i][j] == '.':
            to_visit += 1
            x = i
            y = j


s = [(x, y)]  # a stack for performing DFS
while to_visit > 0 and len(s) > 0:
    i, j = s.pop()
    arr[i][j] = '?'  # make it anything other than '.', '#' and 'X', to mark it visited.
    #                  so we can later remaining '.' to 'X' and change '?' to '.'
    to_visit -= 1
    # top
    if i > 0 and arr[i - 1][j] == '.':
        s.append((i - 1, j))
        arr[i-1][j] = '@'
    # bottom
    if i < n - 1 and arr[i + 1][j] == '.':
        s.append((i + 1, j))
        arr[i+1][j] = '@'
    # left
    if j > 0 and arr[i][j - 1] == '.':
        s.append((i, j - 1))
        arr[i][j-1] = '@'
    # right
    if j < m - 1 and arr[i][j + 1] == '.':
        s.append((i, j + 1))
        arr[i][j+1] = '@'


for row in arr:
    for element in row:
        if element == '?':
            print('.', end="")
        elif element == '.' or element == '@':
            print('X', end="")
        else:
            print(element, end="")
    print("")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I see it now. My cell were getting revisited and to_visit was depleting earlier than it should.

Comment: @RohitRawat You're welcome. It has been my pleasure to help you!